# Unable to find method void org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmOptions.setUseIR(boolean)

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, okhttp

I'm unable to run any tests or run the app or debugger because of `this error:`

```
`Unable to find method void org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmOptions.setUseIR(boolean)`
```

I've tried all of the provided solutions and hit the `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...` option.

[image]

This is an Android Studio project in Kotlin and Java with Jetpack Compose, Retrofit2, OkHttp3.

---

**Update:** Here are my build.gradle files

### build.gradle Project:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0-RC'
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.1'
        fragment_version = "1.3.6"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### build.gradle App:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions")
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    useLibrary("android.test.runner")
    useLibrary("android.test.base")
    useLibrary("android.test.mock")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.moviespotter"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        compose true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.21'
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    testImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.9.2")
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0' //Glide
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.3.1"
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
}
```

Here are a bunch more words so that StackOverflow will accept my edits.  Too much code you say?  Maybe I'm not that great at coding yet and I have way too many dependencies.  I don't know what these things do.  Sometimes I have an idea, but mostly I'm just reading tutorials and documentation and blindly following whatever they say.  Is this enough words yet?

Comment: can you try using a stable kotlin_version instead of RC??

Comment: @ManojPerumarath That was it! Thanks!  I didn't even notice that, nor am I sure how it got there.

I changed the buildscript from 
`ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0-RC'` to `ext.kotlin_version = 1.5.21`

Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it worked. Happy coding mate, stay safe @petestmart

Comment: I stumbled into this issue as well, but I'm willing to use `ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0-RC'`. Any suggestion?

Comment: i also stumbled into this issue as well, i wanted to make use of kotlin_version of 1.7.20  Any suggestion?

Comment: I ran into this issue on 1.8.21 kotlin. I am stuck.

Answer (score 8):

Updating `com.android.tools.build:gradle` version to `7.0.4` fixed it for me

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
```

Answer (score 6):

Duplicated `kotlin-gradle-plugin` in Project's `build.gradle` might mess things up